# Verifying that a File path is a SD card

Tags: android

I've been looking for a way to get the SD card directory for a majority of the day. I've recently found out that the function call [getExternalStorageDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) under some circumstances returns a path that is on-board memory.  I am supporting API 19 and above. 
The common answer stackOverflow gives  to get the SD card path is

> Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

which is not working for my devices because the external storage returned is non-removable memory (Samsung Tab S2).

I've been able to use [getExternalFilesDirs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState()) to return the list of directories, and in my testing it will return two directories, the on-board memory location for the application and the SD card that I've mounted. However the function call 
[isExternalStorageRemovable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#isExternalStorageEmulated(java.io.File))  was not introduced until API 21. This was the clearest candidate that I could find that would have satisfied what I am trying to do, which is make sure that I am actually writing to the external SD Card.

1) Is there a way to verify if the directory returned by getExternalFilesDirs is removable or external in API 19?

2) Can it be assumed that if the only storage use cases are "Internal Memory" and "Internal Memory and SD Card"  that the SD card location will always be returned second from getExternalFilesDirs as has happened in my brief testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've recently found out that the function call getExternalStorageDirectory under some circumstances returns a path that is on-board memory

[External storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). On the vast majority of Android devices, `getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns a location that is part of the on-board flash. That has been the case for ~7 years, since the introduction of Android 3.0.

> Is there a way to verify if the directory returned by getExternalFilesDirs is removable or external in API 19?

If `getExternalFilesDirs()` returns 2+ items, the second and subsequent ones are on removable storage.

> Can it be assumed that if the only storage use cases are "Internal Memory" and "Internal Memory and SD Card"

That is not a safe assumption.

> that the SD card location will always be returned second from getExternalFilesDirs as has happened in my brief testing?

The first entry returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()` is the same as what is returned by `getExternalFilesDir()` (the older, singular form). While the vast majority of Android devices have fixed external storage, there may be some devices where external storage is actually removable. In this case, the Android SDK and framework still consider this to be external storage — after all, that is what the device manufacturer told the firmware to do. And, in this case, the location returned first from `getExternalFilesDirs()` would be physically removable, even if it is not what Android developers typically think of as removable storage. This is a fringe scenario; I cannot name any current device models that have external storage implemented on a removable card.

Also, bear in mind that not all removable storage is in the form of a card. USB OTG thumb drives are also removable storage, as are more traditional thumb drives for those devices that have a USB Type A port (e.g., Android TV, Samsung Galaxy S8 in a DeX dock).

> which is make sure that I am actually writing to the external SD Card.

I *strongly* recommend that you stop thinking in terms of media. Use things like [the Storage Access Framework](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/03/storage-access-framework-faq.html) (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`) to allow the user to choose places to store content from all possibilities at their disposal: external storage, removable storage, Google drive, Windows file servers, etc.